# How do i create a page for my application on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Alright here a simple thing to demonstrate what i am asking

This is the application for example : https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/monstermmorpg

This the page for this application as you can see there is a native play button :

https://www.facebook.com/MonsterMMORPG

Now it is true that i own both but i can not remember how i did it

Now i am starting a new application

I already composed the new application but i can't find how i was composing a binded page for that application

Ty for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to App Details and click Create Page down at the App Page.